# Does lack of email encryption increase spam rating?

Tags: email-server

We have authentication (spf, dkim, dmarc) setup and tested for the many domains on our system, but email it not sent encrypted.

We are trying to find info about how much lack of encryption affects email being place in spam folders, particularly for gmail. Not many email deliverability articles talk about it.

Does anyone have more insight into this topic?

Comment: I don’t, but will note that in this age of free Let’s Encrypt certificates and universal TLS support in mail server software, setting up encryption for email is very easy and doesn’t cost anything. Better to encrypt than not to encrypt.

Comment: If you share the address I entrusted you with, I do not want any business with you. And why should I treat that any different from any other message from someone I want no business with? Never `RCPT TO:<person>` on an open channel.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be specific: encrypting your email (the messages themselves) is different from allowing your SMTP server to use opportunistic TLS when connecting to other SMTP servers and delivering your messages.

The first, *encrypting email messages* (and the associated key management), is still quite complicated and a burden for both your users, the recipients and far from universally supported.
But when a message is encrypted, I'd expect that the spam filter won't have the recipients decryption key and can't evaluate the content of your encrypted message. Spam scoring can then only be done on the message headers, the SMTP envelope data.
I have neither real nor anecdotal evidence if that does or does not increase/decrease the spam score of the message.

The later, configuring your SMTP server to use [opportunistic TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS) and ensuring that the SMTP transaction is encrypted whenever the `STARTTLS` ESMTP feature is supported by the recipients server.

I can't think of a single good reason *not* to support that.

I don't know if the later *improves* deliverability, but it does not *decrease deliverability either*, but it does improve privacy and the overhead of allowing encryption is minimal.  You don't even need to set up and maintain your own TLS certificates (that burden is on the receiver) to use TLS encryption for sending out e-mail. Your mail server can also still deliver e-mail messages to recipients that don't have TLS certificates enabled on their incoming mail server.

Adding TLS support to your own incoming mail servers might admittedly take some more effort.